# MSVC does not allow overloaded -> operator which returns pointer to alias of scalar type

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```cpp
#include <new>

typedef int T;

struct PtrWrapper {
    T* ptr;
    PtrWrapper() : ptr(new T) {}
    T* operator-> () {
        return ptr;
    }
};

void foo() {
    PtrWrapper wrapper;
    //The commented line works
    //wrapper.operator->()->~T();

    wrapper->~T();   // This line does not work.
}
```

This compiles without any error on clang 8.0.0 and gcc 9.2, but not on msvc v19.22, the compiler complains:

```
<source>(18): error C2839: invalid return type 'T *' for overloaded 'operator ->'

<source>(18): error C2300: 'PtrWrapper': class does not have a destructor called '~T'
```

However, if I write `wrapper.operator->()->~T()` instead, it compiles on all three compilers.

Is this a bug with MSVC?

(For more details, see https://godbolt.org/z/tLx8-7)

Comment: Sounds like something to submit through the visual studio Help -> Send Feedback  -> Report a problem system.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yeah, just want to make sure that this is really a bug, not some edge case in the standard.